# Python: TzInfo Translation

Tags: python, tzinfo

I was hoping someone could translate this for me...
datetime = (2022, 7, 27, 14, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST)

I'm hoping this translates to 27th July, 2pm EST...  The "EDT-1 day" is kind of concerning me.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

In [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), there is a library called "zoneinfo". Maybe it can help you.

Comment: I think this is kind of showing me the same thing that I input no?

Comment: It is like a helper to tzinfo, (ZoneInfo is a concrete implementation of the datetime.tzinfo abstract base class, and is intended to be attached to tzinfo, either via the constructor, the datetime.replace method or datetime.astimezone:) I thought it might help you.